# VS2008 - Unable to start debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, asp.net-3.5

[image]

I am getting the error when I try to debug my application, its build successfully also its not showing me any error.But once I start debugging its showing me the error and even Help button redirects some "Not Found" page.

Can anybody please help me out?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What've you tried? The message is pretty clearly suggesting that it's confused over the Framework version

Comment: this application is built up in the .net framework 2.0 and I have both 2 and 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your application compilation must be set to debug = true in your config file.